# NodeJs Classes TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;name&#39; of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a resourceful api using Nodejs. I have created a UserController class which will contain the usual methods. I am trying to assign some variable in my constructor class to use in those methods.

The variable may get changed to some repo class obj at a later date. So i want to know how i can use a variable i set in my constructor in my index function.

nodejs : v4.5.0

When i run navigate to /users/ which calls the index function i get this.

```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;name&#39; of undefined
```

```

Route

```

```
var express    = require('express');
var router     = express.Router();
var controller = require('../controllers/user.controller');
    controller = new controller();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.store);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

```

controller
```

```
'use strict';

var User  = require('../models/user.model');

class UserController {

    constructor() {
        this.name = "NameHere";
    }

    index(req, res) {

        console.log("My Name Is: " + this.name);

    }

    show(req, res) {


    }

    update(req, res) {

    }

    store(req, res) {

    }

    destroy(req, res) {

    }

}

module.exports = UserController;
```

```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding context when calling ES6 method. How to access object from within method called as callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534818/binding-context-when-calling-es6-method-how-to-access-object-from-within-method)

Comment: You need to bind your callback functions to the object: `router.get('/', controller.index.bind(controller) );` otherwise `this` points to `undefined`, because the function will be called without any _context_.

Comment: Oh that looks confusing controller.index.bind(controller) looks horrible :(

Comment: how can i use the arrow function instead in my case? @t.niese

Comment: An arrow function would not look better here. An arrow function will bind the current `this` in which you create the arrow function, so it would be `router.get('/', (req, res, next) => controller.index(req, res, next) );`. What you could do alternative write `this.index = this.index.bind(this)` in your constructor, so you would move your binding to the constructor part and you could continue using `router.get('/', controller.index);`.

Comment: but then i would have to do that for all my controller methods, show,store,delete etc which would build up the constructor right?

Comment: Why do you use an object at all? Http requests are stateless, so every information you store in you controller object is _global_ anyway.

Comment: @t.niese Im still learning yes, could you possibly show me how you would do this? I wanted to do this so i could add in another class to use. Look at this pastebin http://pastebin.com/ykDhKVWH

Answer (score 0):

You would write your routers like that:

**controller**

```
'use strict';

var data = {
  name :  'NameHere'
};


module.exports = {
  index(req, res) {
    console.log("My Name Is: " + data.name);
  },

  show(req, res) {

  },

  update(req, res) {

  },

  store(req, res) {

  },

  destroy(req, res) {

  }
};
```

**Route**

```
var controller = require('../controllers/user.controller');

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.store);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

If you really need to use different instance of your controller or if you need to pass some config options to it then you would do something like that:

**controller**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function( options ) {
  var data = {
    name :  options.name
  };


  return {
    index(req, res) {
      console.log("My Name Is: " + data.name);
    },

    show(req, res) {

    },

    update(req, res) {

    },

    store(req, res) {

    },

    destroy(req, res) {

    }
  };
}
```

**Route**

```
var controller = require('../controllers/user.controller')({
    name : 'some name'
});

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.store);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to use a class for the controller?

Comment: @KayTokyo If you use the class to create only one object out of it, then you should not use a class, but plain objects. If you need to use the controller multiple times, with different options or if you need to pass options to it from outside and if you don't like the `controller.index.bind(controller)` nor the `this.index = this.index.bind(this)`, then you would use the second option I provided.