# error: "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this,props.navigation.navigate')" In React Native

Tags: react-native

[image]

Getting errors when navigating one page to other page in React Native.

error:

> undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this,props.navigation.navigate')

code:

```
import { StackNavigator,NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
 const Navigation = StackNavigator({
   Home : {
    screen : Home
  },
})
export default class App extends React.Component {
  submit = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');

 }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Enter Log</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.input}
          multiline={true}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="Enter Log"
          placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onChangeText={this.handlePassword} />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitButton} onPress={() => submit } >     
                  <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}> Submit </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your method:

```
import { StackNavigator,NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
 const Navigation = StackNavigator({
   Home : {
    screen : Home
  },
})
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Enter Log</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.input}
          multiline={true}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="Enter Log"
          placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onChangeText={this.handlePassword} />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitButton} onPress={this.submit} >     
                  <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}> Submit </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  submit()  {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  }

}
```

Explanation: [Binding context when calling ES6 method. How to access object from within method called as callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534818/binding-context-when-calling-es6-method-how-to-access-object-from-within-method)

Comment: please suggest any link

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing your **onPress value** to this:

   ```
   onPress={this.submit}
   ```
2. Also, I don't see you importing your Home component to where you assign it as a screen.

Comment: gives error after change: Cannot find variable:submit

used link:https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: Have you made any other changes, apart from what I have proposed?
Try leaving just "{submit}" without "this." and without "() =>". The reason behind that is that you don't need to call the submit function, simply pass it.